# Biblatex: use Latin abreviations for page numbers instead of localized ones

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia, naming

When using biblatex for my bibliography in a German document, page numbers are abbreviated with S. x or in case there are two consecutive pages S. xf (where x is the page number). For formatting reasons I would like to use latin abbreviations in those cases (p. for pagina instead of S. for Seite; sq. for sequentia instead of f. etc.).

Changing the language of the entire document or even only of biblatex to Latin instead of German is not an option however, as this would also change some other keywords to their (undesired) Latin translation.

So what do I have to do to convince biblatex to use Latin abbreviations for page numbers instead of the German ones caused by the document language being German?

This is my current language/biblatex package usage setup:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=german,
                   spelling=new,
                   babelshorthands=false
                  ]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british
                   ]{english}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
              bibencoding=utf8,
              maxbibnames=20,
              style=alphabetic,
              sortlocale=auto,
              block=space,
              backref=true,
              backrefstyle=three,
              date=year
              ]{biblatex}
```

Note: I am using LuaLaTex from the latest Miktex2.9 for compilation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

You must override the strings defined in `german.lbx` with something like:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
page = {p\adddot},
sequens = {sq\adddot},
sequentes = {sqq\adddot},
&c.
   }%
```

So you'll have to scan through the list of strings (several hundreds) in german.lbx, and replace those you want to be in Latin form.